# How to bind conditions to yii2 active record queries?

Tags: jquery, yii2

Given this query:

```
Customers::find()

if(isset($request->post('hasPhone')))
->where(['=', 'has_phone', 1])

if(isset($request->post('hasEmail')))
->where(['=', 'has_email', 1])

->orderBy('id DESC');
```

How do I add the `where` clauses to the query if the conditions are met and skip them if they dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = Customers::find()->orderBy('id DESC');

if (isset($request->post('hasPhone'))) {
    $query->andWhere(['has_phone' => 1]);
}
if (isset($request->post('hasEmail'))) {
    $query->andWhere(['has_email' => 1]);
}
```

Remember to actually fetch data with `$query->one()` or `$query->all()`.